# Drupal creating organic groups using drupal_execute

Tags: drupal-6, filefield

I'm trying to create a node programatically and use the Filefield Module to upload a file from a remote url.

The node is being created properly but I can't get the remote url upload working.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with the maintainer of the module the code can actually be copied from the module. It's around 30 lines that deals with the remote url. Once you have that then you can just pass the resulting file into an array and let filefield deal with the rest.